# Why doesn't Donflamingo control Luffy?

Tags: one-piece

Donflamingo can control people using his strings. Why doesn't he use his ability to control Luffy, or Law instead of fighting them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think Doflamingo can only control those who are weaker than him with his strings.

The most powerful man he has been shown affecting with his strings by far is Jozu, but he didn't control him in the same way he did Bellamy, he just froze him still. Jozu couldn't move, but Doflamingo didn't move him around like a puppet either, whether because he couldn't or just didn't bother isn't clear.

I suspect that for people far weaker than Doffy, like Bellamy or Riku, he is able to completely control their movements, for those weaker than himself he is able to stop their movement, but not move them like a puppet, and that those stronger than him, like presumably Kaido, are able to move freely even when he's trying to control them.

Almost no-one in One Piece has any absolute powers, I don't think Doflamingo's puppet ability is magic, I think he is just able to exert a great deal of his strength through his strings. I think Luffy and Law are at the level that Doflamingo could perhaps stop their movements, but he wouldn't be able to puppet them around like Bellamy.

Comment: The same goes for Sanji. Whether he's stronger than Jozu, I'll leave open for debate.

Comment: Also off-topic, Doffy-sama seems to be able to unconsciously control people (like Bellamy), which he probably wouldn't have been able to do with stronger opponents. I too believe he puts force on them with his strings, although it wouldn't explain how he does this unconsciously though. Does he connect them with his nervous-system or something? I mean, he is controlling hundreds of people, keeping up a cage and could still troll around Law...

Comment: Has he controlled someone who knows haki yet?

Comment: @kaine Yes, Sanji and Bellamy.

Comment: @peterraeves when did doffy control sanji? He held him still when they fought, not moved him. After that sanji took the boat away right?

Comment: @kaine yes thats true. He did move bellamy though and bellamy knows haki.

Comment: @Qiri Not sure whether this answer should be updated with the latest events, but the most powerful man he has controlled now is Luffy. He could even manipulate his movements. Also I just noticed but not sure what you mean by *Jozu is als*?

Comment: As Peter Raeves said, Doflamingo managed to control Luffy with his strings. The reason why he didn't attempt to do it earlier wasn't explicitly explained, but I suggest it was either because Doflamingo didn't deem it necessary, or because he expected Luffy, who was in top condition when they first fought, to break free. Going with the answer Qiri provided earlier, Luffy was heavily weakened by the time Doflamingo used Parasite on him, giving Doffy an opportunity; though even then, to Doffy's surprise, he managed to break free anyway.

Answer (score 4):

I think he has to make them weaker and break their mind psychologically before he can control them, like he does with Bellamy.

Comment: like capturing pokemon ? :D

Comment: Yeah sort of .:p

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, Doflamingo is only able to control opponents  stronger or equally strong as him in a limited amount of time, while the latter still don't figure out yet what Doflamingo's power is about.

After they realize his strings Devil fruit power, they can use Haki to break free. However, their Haki must be strong enough to free themselves from Doflamingo's non-Haki strings, and stronger than Doflamingo's Haki in order to overcome his Haki-imbued strings.

> Like when Luffy very recently did it with Gear fourth.

I hope I made sense in the comment above :)

Comment: You don't need to add spoiler warnings, because due to the spoilertag I added, we all know the hidden text will contain a spoiler. That's the great thing about having a spoiler tag, it will hide spoilers automatically :)